# Method signature with no input parameters but with outParam

Tags: objective-c

I'd like to define a method that takes no input parameters but has one or more `outParams`.

I cannot change the method to simply return the type needed by the `outParam` as many of them need multiple `outParam` values and I won't be able to use a collection as the return type.

As a workaround I've been using:

```
- (BOOL)methodName:(NSString*)nothing outParam:(NSData*)foo outParam:(NSData*)bar;
```

I'd like to have something like:

```
- (BOOL)methodName outParam:(NSData*)foo outParam:(NSData*)bar;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Objective-C objects are referenced by pointers, output parameters use double pointers:

```
- (BOOL)methodNameWithOutParam:(NSData* __autoreleasing *)foo
                      outParam:(NSData* __autoreleasing *)bar;
```

This would allow you to allocate autoreleasing `NSData` objects inside the method, and use them in the caller.

This pattern is similar to what's used for dealing with `NSError`s in many iOS APIs. However, this is not ideal, because you have to declare pointers separately from the place where they are set, even though the two places are in close proximity.

In situations like that, chances are that `foo` and `bar` `NSData` objects are closely related. If this is so, consider making a type that "connects" the two together into something meaningful. This would allow you to return a single object instead:

```
@interface BazData
@property (readwrite, nonatomic) NSData *foo;
@property (readwrite, nonatomic) NSData *bar;
@end
...
- (BazData*)methodName;
```

Comment: I'm wanting to get rid of the (NSString*)nothing.

Comment: @haxor This shouldn't be a problem: if you do not want it there, remove it from the signature. If you want it as an output, make it a double-pointer or move it into the `BazData` class (see above).

Comment: I don't want to add a new class.  I just want to get rid of the first (NSString*)nothing from the method signature.  Thanks!

Comment: @haxor Then use the first signature :)

Comment: Is there any way to do this while preserving the outParam syntax?

Comment: @haxor Unfortunately, no: the first `outParam` is always a part of the method name. That's why Objective-C API uses "blahBlah**With**BlahBlah" names all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

Just as many Cocoa methods accept an `NSError **` parameter, you can define your method as follows:

```
- (BOOL)methodWithOutParam:(NSData * __autoreleasing *)foo outParam:(NSData * __autoreleasing *)bar;
```

Make sure you add an extra * where you use those parameters, e.g.

```
*foo = [@"Test" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have the "nothing" input parameter. It's OK if all params are outparams. The distinction between "method name" and "parameter names" is kind of fictional, actually-- they are all part of one selector. So you can call something like this:

```
[self myMethodGetFoo:&foo getBar:&bar getBaz:&baz];
```

Note that there's no "blank space" or "skipped" parameter here. It just uses three outparams. You would define such a method like this:

```
- (BOOL)myMethodGetFoo:(NSData* __autoreleasing *)foo
                getBar:(NSData* __autoreleasing *)bar
                getBaz:(NSData* __autoreleasing *)baz;
```

(as suggested in other answers) Note again that there's nothing "special" about that initial "parameter". You've just decided to use the double pointer to create the outparam.

(If you're a little fuzzy on why the outparams use double pointers for objects, that's a bit of a different concern but a common challenge.)

Comment: Example please?  I've tried - (BOOL)methodName: outParam:(NSString*)foo and it doesn't work

Comment: @haxor: Oh, you don't need to do anything special. That first "parameter" can be an "outparameter". It's up to you what the name and type is of all parameters.

Comment: - (BOOL)foo:outParam:(NSString*)bar; creates a compilation error as does - (BOOL)foo outParam:(NSString*)bar; - how do I do it?

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to do this while preserving the outParam syntax?

Comment: Sure, you can call it literally whatever you want.  "outParam" is not part of the syntax, it's just the name you give it. So you could do `-(BOOL)methodNameOutParam:(NSData* __autoreleasing *)foo outParam:(NSData* __autoreleasing *)bar`